# Why cant I add more then 1 item in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio

So I'm not new to Visual studio, and that's why this is so confusing.

I'm working with an android app and I'm trying to add stuff from the toolbox but it doesn't let me add more than 1 object.

i.e I have my Large text in there and when I try to add a Person name (or anything else) it doesn't let me, even when I double click the item.

I made a gif to visually show what's happening.
[Here is the GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCoVo.gif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it restored and what is crucial to have is this line of code right here

SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

Comment: Thats exactly what was wrong, thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me is that I had to create a new project, not exactly sure on what fixed it but it seems to have restored something that I deleted in the earlier project.

Answer (score 1):

Are you dragging the new item over the existing item?
Ie. Is the Large text that's currently on the form take up the entire form so it is blocking new items?
If so, try resizing the large text first and try adding new items after that.

If that doesn't work, it is possible you are trying to drag a content item into a single collection item that already has a content item in it, you may need a parent collection item to host multiple content items.

Ie.

- Content Item = Label
- Single Collection Item = Button (ie. it can hold a label but without any additional 'collection' you won't be able to fit anything else into it)
- Collection Item = StackPanel / WrapPanel / Grid (think maybe this is a GridLayout in your type of project) (It's job is to contain multiple different child items at once)

Comment: I tried doing vise versa with a smaller item because it seems impossible to resize the items that i drag into the project which is weird

Comment: In most project types, if you click on the item, then hit F4, it will bring up the properties, it should have size properties you can adjust manually.

Comment: It didnt do it for me.

Comment: I changed the layout width and height in the properties but it still does this
https://i.gyazo.com/536c5e2f00dbc20c6db003397c841024.gif

Comment: Updated my answer, give that a go.